Mockmvc.perform with ContentType application/json but then makes request using application/json;charset=UTF8
This is my Test where i test the Controller
mvc.perform(post(URL_DUPLICATE_OBJECTIVE_5).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf()).content(DUPLICATE_OBJECTIVE))

The response i get is this
   Status = 415
    Error message = Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported.
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json, application/yaml, application/*+json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

It's the only test where MockMvc does this wierd behaviour with my ContentType in every other it stays application/json
For Version we use spring-boot 3.4
